# Django DateTimeField not showing up properly in browser

Tags: python, django

I want my django DateTimeField to be inputted the same way I input the values from the admin page, where the dates are selected from a calender.

for reference this is how my models.py look like:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class TheDate(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    theDate = models.DateTimeField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """returns a string representation of the model"""
        return str(self.theDate)
```

forms.py

```
class NewDate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TheDate
        fields = ['theDate']
        labels = {'theDate': ''}
```

the html page where i have set to create a new plan- new_date.html:

```
{% extends "meal_plans/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Add new Date:</p>
  <form action="{% url 'meal_plans:new_date' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Add New Date</button>
  </form>

 {% endblock content %}
```

what can i do to the data be inputted in that way
i hope the code here is enough and relevant.

Comment: Can you share your view? Shouldnt this be a POST request, so `<form ... method="POST">`.

Comment: Try `<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">`? Input type should be date for a drop down calendar.

Comment: But the input format of `type="date"`cannot be changed, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had similar problem and I found something like this

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

And then in your modelform

```
class NewDate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TheDate
        widgets = {
            'theDate': DateInput()
        }
        fields = ['theDate']
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in your forms.py something like this:

```
class NewDate(forms.ModelForm):
    theDate = forms.DateTimeField (
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput (
            attrs={
                'type': 'datetime-local',
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = TheDate
        fields = ['theDate']
        labels = {'theDate': ''}
```

This worked here!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).